# Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.Net 2.0

Tags: asp.net

Please let me know if you have implemented Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.NET 2.0, I have implemented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx#paght000026_step1" mentioned on this page.

But I am getting an error saying "Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Security.RoleProvider".

Would really appreciate if you can please provide some assitance on the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Open a command-line window on your system and run the aspnet_regsql.exe utility that is installed with ASP.NET 2.0 in under your C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.xyz directory. If you will be using Framework 4.0. Go into that directory.  More instructions are here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx. Make sure you go into the database and setup the RoleProvider data for each user.

2) is the database where you have created the asp.net tables with aspnet_regsql.exe the same as your connectionstring OleConnectionStringSource? Here are more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

3) You can configure your datasource in web.config as described or use the Website Administration Tool that changes your web.config automatically.